# REST API : POST/PUT a JSON object VS POST/PUT Key/Value parameters

Tags: rest, backbone.js, restkit

does anyone can help me to decide which is the best practice between :

- using json object to POST/PUT on a REST API
- using key/value parameters instead ?

I realized that Backbone.js and Restkit(IOS) are more json object post/put oriented, But when you want to do an open-third-Party API, how can you decide what is the best approach ?

Comment: What about supporting both and using content negotiation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will win more fans by using JSON to send data.

Servers don't return key/value pairs and mostly JSON or XML.   So front end frameworks have took the initiative of using the same format for exporting as they do importing to keep things consistent.

Answer (score 0):

It is really easy to send a plain JSON object to the server. In case of a framework, it allows you to decrease the code-base (It has nothing about keeping things consistent). But the problem that you can face is that you always must decode the JSON before realizing what is inside. Some people can send you huge JSON-like strings with deep nesting and so on. And your CPU have to handle the conversation process. Facebook, Twitter, Amazon, Instagram are using fields. Github uses objects. In the same time it has 5000 req. limit for a day. And I'm not sure that is what you need. Just think twice.